# Why my chain model keep getting bigger everytime it dublicated by array?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I follow everything on the video but can't find the problem.

[image]

Comment: Would you share the .blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: probably you need to apply the object you use as Object Offset

Comment: You mention a video but could you please provide a link to the video you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Applying the scale of your chain object like this will solve your problem:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*

Comment: you probably mean the object used as Object Offset?

Comment: @moonboots both, because last time I saw this problem in a question here, he had to apply the scale of the object offset also but he had buildings with inequal heights... I tried applying the scale on the arrayed object on his blend file and everything became even again. And I don't think he's using an object as on offset, he's using a curve, so maybe apply the scale of the curve too.

Comment: yes you're right my bad

Comment: Either. It's the _relative_ transform from element  1 to the controlling object that is recursively applied to each successive element.